# apache ant installation on windows 7

Tags: java, ant, installation

I'm new into ANT, I have some trouble to figure the problem.

I set all my varaibles correctly, as:

```
ANT_HOME="C:\Users\Spirithief\Documents\apache-ant-1.8.4"
JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07"
PATH=%ANT_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

I run the cmd line ant I got that the commande does not exists.

I went into the ant.bat in the \bin file I set echo off to echo on.

here the [batch file](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ant/core/tags/ANT_180/src/script/ant.bat) in apache's svn.

The bug apears to be in this line :

```
:stripAntHome
if not _%ANT_HOME:~-1%==_\ goto checkClasspath
```

it said that, it's not reconizable.

NB : echo %ANT_HOME% works great, others as well, so it's not the problem.

Any hints ??

NB : Here's the batch file execution (my system is in french :p):

```
Microsoft Windows [version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Tous droits réservés.

C:\Users\Spirithief>ant

C:\Users\Spirithief>REM  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under
one or more

C:\Users\Spirithief>REM  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file di
stributed with

C:\Users\Spirithief>REM  this work for additional information regarding copyrigh
t ownership.

C:\Users\Spirithief>REM  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache Lice
nse, Version 2.0

C:\Users\Spirithief>REM  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in co
mpliance with

C:\Users\Spirithief>REM  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

C:\Users\Spirithief>REM

C:\Users\Spirithief>REM      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

C:\Users\Spirithief>REM

C:\Users\Spirithief>REM  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writi
ng, software

C:\Users\Spirithief>REM  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS
IS" BASIS,

C:\Users\Spirithief>REM  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either ex
press or implied.

C:\Users\Spirithief>REM  See the License for the specific language governing per
missions and

C:\Users\Spirithief>REM  limitations under the License.

C:\Users\Spirithief>REM This is an inordinately troublesome piece of code, parti
cularly because it

C:\Users\Spirithief>REM tries to work on both Win9x and WinNT-based systems. If
we could abandon '9x

C:\Users\Spirithief>REM support, things would be much easier, but sadly, it is n
ot yet time.

C:\Users\Spirithief>REM Be cautious about editing this, and only add WinNT speci
fic stuff in code that

C:\Users\Spirithief>REM only runs on WinNT.

C:\Users\Spirithief>if "" == "" goto homeDrivePathPre

C:\Users\Spirithief>if "C:\Users\Spirithief" == "" goto userProfilePre

C:\Users\Spirithief>if "C:\Users\Spirithief" == "" goto userProfilePre

C:\Users\Spirithief>if exist "C:\Users\Spirithief\antrc_pre.bat" call "C:\Users\
Spirithief\antrc_pre.bat"

C:\Users\Spirithief>if "C:\Users\Spirithief" == "" goto alpha

C:\Users\Spirithief>if "C:\Users\Spirithief" == "" goto alpha

C:\Users\Spirithief>if "C:\Users\Spirithief" == "C:\Users\Spirithief" goto alpha


C:\Users\Spirithief>if "Windows_NT" == "Windows_NT"

C:\Users\Spirithief>if "Windows_NT" == "WINNT"

C:\Users\Spirithief>if ""C:\Users\Spirithief\Documents\apache-ant-1.8.4"" == ""
goto setDefaultAntHome
La syntaxe de la commande n'est pas correcte.
C:\Users\Spirithief>if not _"==_\ goto checkClasspath
C:\Users\Spirithief>
```

Comment: the syntax of the command line O_O

Comment: how did you set your environment variables? using My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced -> Environment variables?

Comment: and you should not have quotationmarks in your values, i.e. `ANT_HOME=C:\Users\Spirithief\Documents\apache-ant-1.8.4`

Comment: you're right. Same with JAVA_HOME. It's weird, i thought, it's better to quote...

Comment: so you don't have the quotation marks and it still doesn't work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the quotation marks in your environment variables because it is not needed and the ant script is already adding them for you.

Answer (score 1):

Not the answer you asked, but this maybe relevant and should help you :

http://wiki.apache.org/ant/AntOnWindows

and I can personally vouch for : http://code.google.com/p/winant/

I got the link from the wiki, so I would trust it, and also it worked in one shot. :)

Answer (score 0):

FYI, it works for binary distribution (not source-distr.), because the binary contains \bin directory by default.